# Bootstrap Scroll Bar Only Active When Resizing Window

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, scrollbar

I have a single web page that has an annoying visible scroll bar. I want to get rid of the scroll bar when the website is at full screen. I've tried using `overflow-y:hidden;` but the problem with that is when I try to resize the window the navbar pushes all the content down the web page and `overflow-y:hidden;` makes it impossible to scroll to view the content.

I'm not sure if it's something wrong with my background because I'm not using an image, just a gradient, and I don't want my navbar to overlay the website.

Comment: If I understand it correctly: you want to hide the scroll bar only on full screen view and the problem occurs when you start making the window (fullscreened) smaller like for tablet/mobile views, yes?

Comment: you could add a media query to set the overflow-y to hidden only over e.g 1024px width? (and auto below that maybe?)

Comment: @kademat correct. or even just half screening it.